# how could i get the description text above the img herf tag

Tags: python, url, beautifulsoup, web-crawler

i want to get the  description(or title) of picture,and i want to deal the html in batch istead of getting the text by find the xpath by gooolg Inspection tool one by one ，because there is no common rules for all title or description(some picture has no description or title),and the only way seem to find the pic position and find the nearst text around the pic,it is most likely be my target！

```
data=<p style="margin-top:6pt;margin-bottom:0pt;text-indent:4.54%;font-family:Times New Roman;font-size:10pt;font-weight:normal;font-style:normal;text-transform:none;font-variant: normal;">
   The following graph sets forth the cumulative total return to CECO’s shareholders during the five years ended December&nbsp;31, 2018, as well as the following indices: Russell 2000 Index, Standard and Poor’s (“S&amp;P”) 600 Small Cap Industrial Machinery Index, and S&amp;P 500 Index. Assumes $100 was invested on December&nbsp;31, 2013, including the reinvestment of dividends, in each category.
</p>
<p style="margin-top:6pt;margin-bottom:0pt;text-indent:4.54%;font-family:Times New Roman;font-size:10pt;font-weight:normal;font-style:normal;text-transform:none;font-variant: normal;">
  <img src="gfsqvgqkrgf1000002.jpg" title="" alt="" style="width:649px;height:254px;">
</p>
```

**What I want is :
The following graph sets forth the cumulative total return to CECO’s shareholders during the five years ended December 31, 2018, as well as the following indices: Russell 2000 Index, Standard and Poor’s** [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NCFsU.jpg)

*this is what i try:*

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(data, 'lxml')
print(soup.select_one("p > img").find_previous('p'))
```

## but this is not what i want

Comment: Please add the code you tried and what do you get as output vs. expected

Comment: i put it ,i want to find the  <img> tag's elder uncle nodes,but the output is always its parent

Answer (score 0):

You can capture the text by first searching for `<p>` tag which contains `<img>` and then by function `find_previous()` search for previous `<p>` tag with description:

```
data = '''<p style="margin-top:6pt;margin-bottom:0pt;text-indent:4.54%;font-family:Times New Roman;font-size:10pt;font-weight:normal;font-style:normal;text-transform:none;font-variant: normal;">
   The following graph sets forth the cumulative total return to CECO’s shareholders during the five years ended December&nbsp;31, 2018, as well as the following indices: Russell 2000 Index, Standard and Poor’s (“S&amp;P”) 600 Small Cap Industrial Machinery Index, and S&amp;P 500 Index. Assumes $100 was invested on December&nbsp;31, 2013, including the reinvestment of dividends, in each category.
</p>
<p style="margin-top:6pt;margin-bottom:0pt;text-indent:4.54%;font-family:Times New Roman;font-size:10pt;font-weight:normal;font-style:normal;text-transform:none;font-variant: normal;">
  <img src="gfsqvgqkrgf1000002.jpg" title="" alt="" style="width:649px;height:254px;">
</p>'''

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(data, 'lxml')

print(soup.select_one('p:has(img)').find_previous('p').text.strip())
```

Prints:

> The following graph sets forth the cumulative total return to CECO’s
>   shareholders during the five years ended December 31, 2018, as well as
>   the following indices: Russell 2000 Index, Standard and Poor’s (“S&P”)
>   600 Small Cap Industrial Machinery Index, and S&P 500 Index. Assumes
>   $100 was invested on December 31, 2013, including the reinvestment of
>   dividends, in each category.

Comment: good idea,but it  not work !  NotImplementedError: Only the following pseudo-classes are implemented: nth-of-type.

Comment: @李文举, you would need to upgrade to Beautiful Soup 4.7+ or install `soupsieve` and then import and use it's API directly `soupsieve.select_one('p:has(img)', soup).find_previous('p').text.strip())`. https://github.com/facelessuser/soupsieve

Comment: @李文举 Another way to do that (without upgrading) is to use `soup.select_one("p > img").find_previous('p').find_previous('p').text`. A little silly, but it works.

Comment: @李文举 I'm using version `beautifulsoup4==4.7.1`